# tmux: Difference between bind and bind-key

Tags: shortcut-keys, tmux

What's difference in `tmux` between :

```
bind

bind-key
```

only the first works to address Control Spacebar, `C-Space`

Please clarify.

Comment: `bind` is just an alias of `bind-key`. Read `man tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

From `man tmux`:

> Commands related to key bindings are as follows:
>
> ```
> bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]
> ```
>
> (alias: `bind`) Bind key key to command.

They do the same thing.

If you have a tested scenario where they do not behave the same, better file a bug report.