# Remap the tmux `C-b ]` paste clipboard shortcut key into another

Tags: shortcut-keys, clipboard, tmux

How is correct way to remap/re-bind the tmux `C-b ]` paste clipboard shortcut key into another key sequence shortcut ?

Answer (score 1):

The `tmux` command you want to bind is `paste-buffer`. And [you already know](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1476537/tmux-difference-between-bind-and-bind-key) that the command to bind a key is `bind-key` (or `bind`).

Simply use the syntax `bind-key key command` to bind the `paste-buffer` command to another key than <kbd>]</kbd> (still used together with prefix).

For example, if you want to bind this command to <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>½</kbd>, add this to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind ]
bind ½ paste-buffer
```

If you want to bind this command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>½</kbd> (overriding the prefix key), add this to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind ]
bind -n C-½ paste-buffer
```

The `-n` option adds the keybinding to the `root` table (ignoring the prefix key), and `C-` adds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as a modifier key.

Everything in this answer is documented in `man tmux`.